# New notification should not cancel the previous notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Thanks for viewing. I don't want to replace previous notification with new, when notification is fired. In my case, notification are getting replaced. Notifications should be cleared only, if user presses android built-in clear notifications option.  Thanks for your help mates.

Here it is, what i've tried:

```
  Intent notifyIntent =
                    new Intent(new Intent(this, Dashboard_DrawerMain.class));
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
            notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notifyIntent
                   , 0);

            mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                                    .setContentTitle(str_SenderName)
                                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                                    .setContentText(str_Message)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true);



               mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ft_icon);


            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Did you google for it? Did you at least read `NotificationManager.notify` documentation?

Comment: @Selvin google? what is google?

Answer (score 0):

Please use differnt NOTIFICATION_ID on NotificationManager.notify

Answer (score 0):

If the NOTIFICATION_ID is unique then the system will consider it as a new notification

```
   mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

But it is better to replace the notification if it is just an update to previous notification

Answer (score 0):

Create the new Notification with a new ID and it won't clear the previous one.